# IPhone View Based Application Go to Main View

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

In my view-based application,it includes three views.First View(Main View) call second view.Second view call third view(detail view). I want to add home function in third view to go back first view(Main View).
Currently I add Home button in third view.But I don't know how to write this function.       The following is my code:

```
//In First view(main view)
//call second view(list view) in button click
-(IBAction) doctorList:(id)sender
{   
    if(self.doctorViewController==nil)
    {
        DoctorViewController *doctorView=[[DoctorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DoctorViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.doctorViewController=doctorView;
        [doctorView release];
    }

    self.view addSubview:self.doctorViewController.view];}
}

//In second View(list view)
//Call third view in table cell click
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    DoctorItem *physician=[[DoctorItem alloc]init];
    physician=(DoctorItem*)[self.tableDataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    DoctorDetail *detail=[[DoctorDetail alloc]init];[tableView.superview addSubview:detail.view];
    [physician release];
}
```

In third view,there is a button with label text 'Home'
When user click this button,I want to add go back to first view(main view). I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see any mention of UINavigationControllers in Phoenix's posting... so if I were fixing this code, I'd create an IBAction method like this:

```
- (IBAction) homeButtonPressed: (id) sender
{
    // and remove the subviews

    NSArray * subviews = [self.view subviews];
    for(UIView * aSubview in subviews)
    {
        // this removes and releases the subviews you allocated
        [aSubview removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

and connect your button action to that method.

Also, I'd recommend subclassing UIView and not UIViewController for DoctorView and DoctorViewController. You don't need the extra baggage that UIViewControllers bring if you're just adding subviews onto the root view controller.

Comment: I test your code.It can't solve my problem.It removes all ui subviews from third view only.I mean I want to go back to main view(first view) when user click home button.

Comment: if you put that method in your main root controller, it'll remove all subviews (the second and the third) from your root (first) view controller.  But yeah, in general, using a UINavigationController and pushing / popping stuff is preferable.  :-)

Comment: I put that method in my main root controller. I don't know how to invoke this method from third view.

Comment: I invoked this method via AppDelegate class.But it clears all of subviews includes textviews, label.Actually I want to remove only second and the third view.How can I know this subview is second view or third view?

Comment: I found the solution.To check view type,isKindOfClass method can be used.'code' if([some_object isKindOfClass:[A_Class_Name class]]){}

Comment: You do not need to do this. You can just do a `popToRootView` and it will do it. Although this code solves the problem, this code is just redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just navigating between view controllers, you can just perform a `popToRootViewController` in the last view controller, and this will take you back to the `rootViewController` (your main view).

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix Kyaw,

Try this,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
```

Here homeView is your homeViewController(whereever you want to go)instance..

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one.....

```
[self.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

This worked for me

```
[self.view addSubview:firstViewController.view];
```

or try this

```
[self presentModalViewController:firstViewController animated:YES]; // this is deprecated in ios6.0
```